# user and group join model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the models User and Group, and the join table Membership which uses has_many :through method. In my join table's form, I want the user to input a valid group name that an administrator has created to become a member of that group.

I have gotten the case where a valid name is entered to work but now I need some validation if they input a blank text box, or that the inputted group name exists in the database, I'd like some nice error messages. I thought this would be possible through some validates method?

membership partial **_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@membership) do |f| %>
  <% if @membership.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@membership.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this membership from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @membership.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :group %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :group %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**membership.rb**

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :user_id, :group_id

  validates_uniqueness_of :group_id, :message => "can be only joined once", :scope => 'user_id'
  validates_presence_of :group, :user
end
```

**group.rb**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions

  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

  attr_accessible :name, :expiry
end
```

So need some direction as how the validation happens because the above validation in the membership and group models doesn't work, I get the error for both empty text box or name not in the database...

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

Edit: Added controller code below

```
  def create
    @group = Group.find_by_name(params[:membership][:group])
    @membership = current_user.memberships.build(:group_id => @group.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @membership.save
        format.html { redirect_to membership_url, :notice => 'Membership was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @membership, :status => :created, :location => @membership }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json=> @membership.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question by changing the text input box to a select field, and will add a password field to the model to solve my issue of unwanted users joining the group.

```
  def create
    @groups = Group.current
    @group = Group.find_by_name(params[:membership][:group])
    @membership = current_user.memberships.build(:group_id => @group.id)
```

After which my model validation works now below

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :group_id, :message => "can be only be joined once", :scope => 'user_id'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your group model:

```
validate_uniqueness_of :name, :message => "a group already exists with that name"
validate_presence_of :name
```

The validations are called for all tables you are inserting to.

Edit:

Change your controller like this:

```
@membership = current_user.memberships.build(:group => @group)
```

You won't get the id called on nil error anymore. And if @group is nil, the validation in your membership will pick it up on the save attempt.

Comment: This is validation for inputting the group name, I want some validation in my membership model as if I post an empty text box, or a text box that has a name which doesn't exist, it fails with the error: Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id